# php remove duplicates from a string

Tags: php, function

The following code works but the results arnt being displayed as i require.
if i use the word Anagram the output result is

Anagram Anagram Anagram Anagram Anagram Anagram

This is due to there being no other words that can be made from Anagram but why the result is being duplicated 6 times is my concern.

If i change the word in the code to Listen it will result in the list of anagrams

Listen Inlets Silent Tinsel Enlist

Can anyone help please?

```
<?php 
function permute($str, $l, $r, $pspell_link) 
{ 
    if ($l == $r) {
        if (pspell_check($pspell_link, $str)) {
            echo "<p>".ucwords($str)."</p>";
        };
    }
    else
    { 
        for ($i = $l; $i <= $r; $i++) 
        { 
            $str = swap($str, $l, $i); 
            permute($str, $l + 1, $r, $pspell_link); 
            $str = swap($str, $l, $i);
        } 
    } 
} 
function swap($a, $i, $j) 
{ 
    $temp; 
    $charArray = str_split($a); 
    $temp = $charArray[$i] ; 
    $charArray[$i] = $charArray[$j]; 
    $charArray[$j] = $temp; 
    return implode($charArray); 
} 

$str = "anagram"; 
$n = strlen($str);

$pspell_link = pspell_new("en"); 
permute($str, 0, $n - 1, $pspell_link); 
?>
```

Comment: Instead of echoing the result inside the function (it's generally not a good idea to do this anyways), you should _return_ an _array_ of words. Replace your echo statement with `return array_unique(explode(' ', $str));` Using `array_unique()` will ensure that the words are never repeated. Using `return` is better in functions because it allows the person running the function to actually _use_ the results, instead of just echoing them straight to the page where the function was ran. If you want to display them how you are now, use `echo implode(' ', permute());`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thanks for your comment, i altered my code as you suggested but it didnt seem to display anything. Although i may have implimented it wrong?

Comment: Yes, the function won't display anything anymore. It will _return_ it, so that means you have to do the display part outside of the function. Basically, when you run the `permute()` function, assign it to a variable. `$permutations = permute($str, 0, $n - 1, $pspell_link);` then you can do `echo implode(' ', $permutations);`

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed

Comment: That means your function is not returning an array.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Thanks for your help anyway

Answer (score 0):

This happens whenever the word contains duplicate letters. When it swaps a letter with a copy of itself, such as the first and third letters in `anagram`, the new word is also in the dictionary, so it gets printed again.

You should skip those cases in the `for` loop. Also, you should start the loop at `$i = $l+1`, so it doesn't swap a letter with itself.

```
    for ($i = $l+1; $i <= $r; $i++) 
    { 
        if ($str[$l] == $str[$l]) {
            continue;
        }
        $str = swap($str, $l, $i); 
        permute($str, $l + 1, $r, $pspell_link); 
        $str = swap($str, $l, $i);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your time unfortunatly when i tried to add the code it didnt echo any result.